# How can I use pre-trained yolov3 model and retrain train it to detect more than 80 objects

Tags: object-detection, training-data

I am using yolov3 model to detect the object. And it is able to detect 80 object.

But now I want to custom train existing model for 3 new classes and I don't want to loose pre-trained object. In other words, I want to incrementally train the model.

So, In final result I expecting that my new model will be able to detect total 83 objects.

I have followed [AlexeyAB/Darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet). But at the end I am only able to detect last 3 object which i trained. And loose that 80 predefined classes.

How can I train model so it will add new classes after existing classes?

Comment: Hi. Have you found a way to do this yet? I am also trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, you need to train your network on *all* the dataset used to train the 80 classes of Yolo. If you only train on your 3-classes dataset the network will "forget" the old classes it learns.

This dataset is probably COCO, you can find it online, but you should know that training a network from scratch takes lots of time.